# Issue while converting from const string to const u8_t *

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I have the following code

In .hpp file

```
class A
{
 private:
   static std::string hello;
}
```

In .cpp file

```
const std::string hello= "hi";

B(hello, strlen(hello)); // where B(const u8_t* a, u8_t b)
```

Which cast should I use?
I want to convert const string to `const u8_t *` eventually.
u8_t is unsigned char

Comment: `hello.c_str()` ?

Comment: don't use `u8_t`. Use `uint8_t` in `<cstdint>`

Comment: what is `u8_t`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: u8_t = unsigned char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u8_t` is a non-standard type. I'll assume it's the same as the standard `uint8_t`.

Another unanswered question is whether the `B` type treats null bytes in any special way, I'll assume not.

So `strlen(hello)` doesn't compile. That should be replaced by `hello.size()`, which is the correct way to get the size of a C++ string.

Finally to answer your question, `std::string` has a `data` method that returns a pointer to the character data. That pointer is type `char*` which you will then need to cast to `u8_t*` for your constructor.

So putting that together you get

```
B(reinterpret_cast<u8_t*>(hello.data()), hello.size());
```

Comment: Is that a good practice to promote? Shouldn't he/she/they use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (or `memcpy` pre c++20)?

Comment: John, I got this error -  "reinterpret_cast cannot cast away const or other type qualifiersC/C++(694)". By using hello.size() , I no longer have issue in that. But still having issue in casting.

Comment: @RajLavingia OK if `hello` is `const` just change the code to this `B(reinterpret_cast<const u8_t*>(hello.data()), hello.size());`.